# Malicious search attempts showing in Popular Search Terms in Magento?

Tags: security, magento

If you go here, you would be met with a full page of malicious search attempts at my Magento store: http://www.princessly.com/catalogsearch/term/popular/

My question is, what can be done to prevent malicious search phrases from showing up on the Popular Search Terms page yet still show legitimate search terms from good-will users?

Thanks!

Comment: So you're looking for some kind of spam filter, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't list searches which don't return results**, or which return only “sloppy” matches. The “malicious searches” presumably don't match any product on your site, so they will be excluded by this rule.

This rule does not require you to recognize the specific form of the searches in any way (it is not a blacklist), so it is robust. Furthermore, listing ordinary searches for which there are no results will likely not benefit you or your customers, so excluding them will be an improvement beyond taking care of the spam problem.

Comment: thanks a lot for the useful insight. So how can I do this in Magento? How can I not list searches that don't return matched results? Is there any configurable options in the admin panel or do I have to hard code it in my templates?

Comment: Don't know, sorry. I'm not familiar with Magento; I just thought this idea was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

First check if the injection search terms are evaluated, or in other words if the seach terms are properly escaped and filtered to prevent sql injection. Then proceed to clean the database of the indexed search terms. 
Next I would have a look into the indexing function, if you have sufficient sql injection and xss protection in the search function you don't really need to worry about that (unless it is eating up your bandwidth, then you might want to look into blacklisting IPs or active search filtering which however will be little more complicated). Essentially you only want to store proper queries, the easiest way would be to simply only store alphabetical queries, but that could be very restrictive and exclude other valid queries. Conversely you can employ a blacklist and regex checks, but that will be little more difficult to implement and timely. 
Lastly you may want to impose search limit say per time period, and things like useragent checks to ensure that a person is actually searching. You could also employ CAPTCHA of some sort, but that could severely deter users from using the search function extensively, so I would discourage that.

Answer (score 0):

Malicious search terms can be somehow enumerated, so when that happen the developer build a set of regular expressions to check whether an entered search term/query is clean or not, for example let's take `' OR '1'='1` SQL-Injection as a search input:

Target: Prevent `' OR '1'='1` from being captured in the database.
HOWTO: Apply a regular expression, e.g. `^'?1 (')? [Oo][Rr] (')?1(')?=1(')?$` if that regular expression returned true, then block the term from being captured, if we wanna add more blocked terms, we can do something similar to this `^('?1 (')? [Oo][Rr] (')?1(')?=1(')?)|(Other Regex)^`. However if the terms are already captured, then cleaning the database would be the best possible solution, cause if we attempted to do a Regex check each time a popular search term is about to be shown, the site performance would decrease, so my suggestion is to clean up the database by running a regular expression over the popular terms table and delete the row with the malicious intention.